# Setting a WPF ContextMenu's PlacementTarget property in XAML?

Tags: wpf, xaml, button, contextmenu

```
<Button Name="btnFoo" Content="Foo" >
    <Button.ContextMenu Placement="Bottom" PlacementTarget="btnFoo">
        <MenuItem Header="Bar" />
    </Button.ContextMenu>
</Button>
```

gives me a runtime error 'UIElement' type does not have a public TypeConverter class

I also tried

```
<Button Name="btnFoo" Content="Foo" >
    <Button.ContextMenu Placement="Bottom" PlacementTarget="{Binding ElementName=btnFoo}">
        <MenuItem Header="Bar" />
    </Button.ContextMenu>
</Button>
```

and that put the ContextMenu in the top left corner of my screen, rather than at the Button

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You should be setting the ContextMenuService.Placement attached property on the button, as stated in the remarks in the documentation for [ContextMenu.Placement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.contextmenu.placement.aspx).

```
<Button Name="btnFoo" Content="Foo" ContextMenuService.Placement="Bottom">
    <Button.ContextMenu>
        <ContextMenu>
            <MenuItem Header="Bar" />
        </ContextMenu>
    </Button.ContextMenu>
</Button>
```

Comment: @VitalyB: As the MSDN docs states, the PlacementTarget property is changed when the context menu opens (to either MousePoint or Center, depending on how the user opens the menu). Because of this, setting a binding on the property will not work - it will be changed.

Comment: Oh... I see. They should've marked it as read-only, that would be less confusing. Thanks!

Comment: When this is implemented the context menu comes on right click of the mouse. Is it possible to bring the context menu on left click of the mouse? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

Have you tried this:

```
<Button Name="btnFoo" Content="Foo">
    <Button.ContextMenu>
        <ContextMenu>
            <MenuItem Header="Bar" />
        </ContextMenu>
    </Button.ContextMenu>
</Button>
```

This will make the ContextMenu open where you right clicked your mouse (on the button).
Which I think might be your desired location right?

--- EDIT ---
In that case use this:

```
<Button Name="btnFoo" Content="Foo" ContextMenuOpening="ContextMenu_ContextMenuOpening">
    <Button.ContextMenu>
        <ContextMenu Placement="Bottom">
            <MenuItem Header="Bar" />
        </ContextMenu>
    </Button.ContextMenu>
</Button>
```

And in code behind:

```
private void ContextMenu_ContextMenuOpening(object sender, ContextMenuEventArgs e)
{
    // Get the button and check for nulls
    Button button = sender as Button;
    if (button == null || button.ContextMenu == null)
        return;
    // Set the placement target of the ContextMenu to the button
    button.ContextMenu.PlacementTarget = button;
    // Open the ContextMenu
    button.ContextMenu.IsOpen = true;
    e.Handled = true;
}
```

You can reuse the method for multiple buttons and ContextMenu's..

Comment: the project I work on long ago began using Buttons and ContextMenus to create a ComboBox effect. while this is probably a little silly, it's too late to change it now. So I want the ContextMenu to open beneath the Button, not wherever the click actually occurred.

Comment: When this is implemented the context menu comes on right click of the mouse. Is it possible to achieve the same functionality on left click of the mouse? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a `<Menu />`, styled as a `Button` and avoid the hassle with the `ContextMenuService`.